# How can I align the button on the left with the links in the centre for a collapsible navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using a collapsible navbar where the button only appears when the window is small enough. So I'd like the links aligned center, and the button aligned left, whenever the window is small.

The problem seems to happen when I include certain Bootstrap classes on the button, those classes for some reason force the links to align left.

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light justify-content-center">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="NavbarLinks" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Home.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="NavbarLinks" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Services.php">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li id="NavbarLinks" class="navabr-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="BookAppointment.php">Book Appointment</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying something like this? If I'm understanding right you want the toggle button to be on the left side, but the links themselves at the center when the navbar expands?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav  mx-auto">
      <li id="NavbarLinks" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Home.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="NavbarLinks" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Services.php">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li id="NavbarLinks" class="navabr-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="BookAppointment.php">Book Appointment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When the window is big enough I want the navbar to just be a standard navbar, no toggle button and links in the center, when the window is smaller, I want the links to disappear and the toggle button to appear, on the left. I tried adding the text-center class, however it only centers the text when the navbar is collapsed, which is super weird. It has no affect when the navbar is expanded. I also tried adding the class to the nav tag, it does the same thing

Comment: @BradyHarper Ok, I just want to be clear, you want the links to be always centered? Either when the navbar y fully displayed and when it is collapsed and expanded?

Comment: @BradyHarper check the answer again

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS, using `@media`. Here is an example (I am not sure if this is what you want)

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        left: 0px;
    }
    .nav-item {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I explained it very well in the initial question. So firstly, I had a standard navbar with the links aligned in the center. Then I added the button and collapsible classes, this made the links align to the left. The button is also aligned to the left, when the window is small enough. I'm trying to get the button aligned to the left, and the links aligned center. I tried your solution but it didn't change anything

Comment: @BradyHarper Could you maybe try to post all your code? It will make it easier to identify the problem